# doctrine with clause on left join not working

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have a `Users` entity and `Comment` entity. User can have many comments. In user and in comment I have `enabled` flag.

Here is the entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private bool $enabled;

    /**
     * @var Collection<Comment>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment",
     *     mappedBy="user",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
     *     orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     */
    private Collection $comments;

    public function __construct(
        array $comments,
        bool $enabled
    ) {
       $this->enabled = $enabled;
       $this->comments = new ArrayCollection($comments);
    }
}
```

and `Comment`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    public bool $enabled;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    public User $user;

    public function __construct(
        User $user,
        bool $enabled,
    ) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }
}
```

And I need to get all enabled users and for each enabled user all their enabled comments, here is the query I have in my repository:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')
    ->leftJoin(
        'user.comments',
        'comment',
        Expr\Join::WITH,
        'comment.enabled = :commentEnabled'
    )
    ->setParameter('commentEnabled', true, Types::BOOLEAN)
    ->where('user.enabled = :userEnabled')
    ->setParameter('userEnabled', true, Types::BOOLEAN)
    ->orderBy('user.id', 'ASC');

   $query = $qb->getQuery();

   return $query->execute();
```

and all is fine with users, I'm getting only enabled users, but also I'm getting all comments not only enabled...
also I tried query like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
    ->leftJoin(
        'user.comments',
        'comment',
    )
    ->where('user.enabled = :enabled')
    ->andwhere('comment.enabled = :enabled')
    ->setParameter('enabled', true, Types::BOOLEAN)
    ->orderBy('user.id', 'ASC');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->execute();
```

and result is the same.

It's driving me crazy because it's trivial task... and it's not working. Can some please tell me where I made a typo...

Comment: what is weird, is when I'm execution result of `$qb->getQuery()->getSql()` directly in database result is correct....

Comment: one more weirdness...  `$qb->getQuery()->execute()` or `$qb->getQuery()->getResuot()` returning wrong result, but `$qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()` returning correct data as array....

Comment: I guess it can be somehow related to lazy loading, when I'm calling some property it simply loads all related data, but it's defeating purpose of using such a query, only if returning array instead of entity?